# How does "sp_updatestats" boosts up the Data Access?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

How Does Using "**sp_updatestats"** boosts the system. I am using Medium instance of Azure for one of my project and facing regular timeout issues while fetching data. But when I run this query in DB it works incredibly fast and data loads in flash of seconds.

Can anybody explain me the irony of this?
Am I doing something wrong in my code?
Can this be because of Unclosed connections?
I am using PetaPoco, EF and ADO.net as DB Access Techniques

PLEASE HELP, THANKS IN ADVANCE 
**#SickOfTimeOuts**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_updatestats` procedure rebuild statistics information on all statistic objects in the database. If you're loading lots of data on a regular basis, then it's perfectly ok to expirience these slowdowns and to fix them with update statistic info after that. But if not, then your problem most likely has nothing to do with stale statistics, but rather with parameter sniffing. 
Identify the statements that run slowly, and add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to them.
Don't know if you're doing anything wrong with your code, probably not, but I didn't see any of it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - can you please tell me where should I implement the code to update stats on regular basis, "Worker Role" Or just before the statements where it executes complex queries?

Comment: With op premise instance you'd probably schedule a job and update stats from there. There is no SQL Sgent on Azure, but there are plenty of resources around the web how to schedule some task, including the worker role. Never had a pleasure to maintain an Azure solution myself, so I'd rather not compare those solutions. But, did you explore the other path of enquiry, about the parameter sniffing?

Comment: Naah, Not Yet, But now I got the basic idea how to By Pass this issue, I am reading more about it and will hopefully find a solution. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're wlecome. Accept or upvote so the other can benefit from the answer.